# How to save formatted MS Outlook email body with HTML elements into MS Access table?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I tried this simple code:

```
Sub sendOutlookEmail()
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As MailItem
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")

Set oMail = oApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

Dim HTMLBody As String
HTMLBody = oMail.HTMLBody

HTMLBody = Replace(HTMLBody, Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34), 1)

Dim sql As String
sql = "UPDATE email_body set email_body = " & Chr(34) & HTMLBody & Chr(34)

Debug.Print sql
CurrentDb.Execute sql

Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

This simple code saves the body of the email to my MS Access table with all HTML elements. Later on, I want to run this code:

```
Sub sendOutlookEmail()
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As MailItem
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")

Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim sql As String
sql = "Select email_body from email_body"

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)

oMail.Body = rs("email_body")
oMail.Subject = "email sent from ms access using vba 2"
oMail.To = "receiver@somthing.com"

oMail.Display

Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

That code should take whatever was stored in my MS Access table and create a new email. What it does though, it copies the literal HTML code into the body of the email which is obviously not what I want. Is there a way to get it displayed the proper way?

Comment: Sounds like you need [`MailItem.HTMLBody`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody)

Comment: Why do you have `oMail.Body` in the second `Sub`?

Comment: Lol, you're right. it should be `oMail.HTMLBody` works perfect now. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`MailItem.HTMLBody` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody), as opposed to the [`MailItem.Body` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.body).

> [The `HTMLBody` property] returns or sets a String representing the HTML body of the specified item. [It is both] read/write.